# ICACLS for a remote group on a remote machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, icacls

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/686592/icacls-for-a-local-group-of-a-remote-machine) concerned a local group. I'm trying to use icacls for a remote group.

I've tried this way, but it didn't work :

```
> icacls \\HOST\shared_dir\file.txt /grant "HOST\GROUP":F
HOST\GROUP: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

Does icacls work for remote groups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you'll either need to execute that on the remote server HOST or from a powershell remoting session to HOST.  Your local machine doesn't know who HOST\GROUP is.

<strike>You could probably use the SID, like the accepted answer on the linked question suggested.</strike>

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work... Sounds like icacls won't set permission if the SID/name isn't defined locally... Error message is : "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.”

Comment: Accepted since I decided to use a remote powershell command. Thanks !